# How to avoid additional whitespaces and "\r\n" being inserted in render tree in Blazor

Tags: html, css, razor, blazor

For following example codes

```
<div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        <span class="@classes[i]">@i</span>
    }
</div>
```

What I want to display is (with each character in different style)

> 01234567890

but what actually display is (additional whitespace between each characters)

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

I use ILSpy to investigate what happens in the render tree, and found following

```
        __builder.OpenElement(2, "div");
        __builder.AddMarkupContent(3, "\r\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            __builder.AddContent(4, "        ");
            __builder.OpenElement(5, "span");
            __builder.AddAttribute(6, "class", classes[i]);
            __builder.AddContent(7, i);
            __builder.CloseElement();
            __builder.AddMarkupContent(8, "\r\n");
        }
        __builder.CloseElement();
```

The sequence 4 adds additional whitespaces and sequence 8 adds "\r\n", which I believe is the reason of the additional whitespace between characters.

I could mitigate the issue by writing in this way

```
<div>@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{<span class="@classes[i]">@i</span>}
</div>
```

However, when there are more and different contents in the same line, the code would be very long. Also when I press Ctrl+D to format the document, in some scenarios VS would "fix" the code in wrong way.

I would like to see if there's any better suggestion for this issue. I thought about following (but couldn't find solution yet)

1. Use CSS to ignore whitespaces and \r\n between spans
2. Somehow add extra @{} to help formatting.
3. Some magic parameter to avoid whitespaces and \r\n added to the render tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are still using aspnetcore 3.x, as this was fixed in .NET5.

Try it in a .NET5 Blazor project - it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just want to add some additional findings.
I think what happens with .NET 5.0 is that the additional whitespaces and "\r\n" around {} are removed, but not all of them are removed. Therefore, it would still break if the case is like <span>1</span>\r\n<span>2</span>. However, could format it much better using {}, like @{<span>1</span>}\r\n@{<span>2</span>}. It still doesn't fully work with Ctrl+D, sometimes after Ctrl+D the code would be totally messed up.